# Kill a process and wait for the process to exit

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process, kill-process

When I start my tcp server from my bash script, I need to kill the previous instance (which may still be listening to the same port) right before the current instance starts listening.

I could use something like `pkill <previous_pid>`. If I understand it correctly, this just sends `SIGTERM` to the target pid. When `pkill` returns, the target process may still be alive. Is there a way to let `pkill` wait until it exits?

Comment: Could you make the same question but in [unix.se] site?

Comment: Here is my solution which works for services too: http://pastebin.com/VjpVNdz2.

Comment: Why is this "off topic"? It is a programming question relevant to the bash programming language.

Comment: it's a pitty that fundamental needs are not solved up to now. I guess there are several thousand scripts which implement this simple feature: kill and wait until process has terminated. How to change the current situation? How to get to the goal?

Comment: Relevant answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427133

Answer (score 41):

No. What you can do is write a loop with `kill -0 $PID`. If this call fails (`$? -ne 0`), the process has terminated (after your normal `kill`):

```
while kill -0 $PID; do 
    sleep 1
done
```

(kudos to [qbolec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575699/qbolec) for the code)

Related:

- [What does `kill -0 $pid` in a shell script do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012527/what-does-kill-0-pid-in-a-shell-script-do)

Comment: Changed it to `while $(kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null); do` to ignore the "No such proccess" message after the proccess was killed

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't kill the process, just looped infinitely. I think you need to actually run `kill $PID` within the while loop

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `kill -0` does not actually kill the process, it simply checks whether the process is still running

Answer (score 2):

Use `wait` (bash builtin) to wait for the process to finish:

```
 pkill <previous_pid>
 wait <previous_pid>
```

Comment: wait said "is not a pid of this shell", I had to `while ps -p $nPid; do sleep 1;done;`

Comment: −1: `wait` only works for children of the _current shell_, not arbitrary processes. There is no general built-in mechanism for this.

Comment: why not use `kill` ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was easier to use the name of the process. It works like this:

```
pkill <process_name> && while pgrep -l <process_name>; do sleep 1;done;
```

Then, restart the process.