# Check if process is running by using PID

Tags: groovy, process

In Groovy, is there a way to check if the program is still running by using the PID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a way to check if the program running ,To check for the existence of a process, use

```
kill -0 $PID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill` command with [`0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11012755/313516) signal. Sample code in Groovy:

```
"kill -0 ${pid}".execute().waitFor()
```

`0` as a returned value means the process is still running.